# Concurrent licensing software

Tags: asset-management

I am looking for a product that will control 4 licenses so that they can be concurrently distributed to 8 users.
One of our depts bought 4 concurrent user licenses only to find out that the company no longer provides a concurrent licensing facility!
There are lots of SAM products out there but all I am looking for is the concurrent facility.

Thanks

Comment: You *bought* a concurrent license? Then it's the vendor's duty to ensure that the license conditions are met, isn't it? Of course there are companies that have a quite lax handling of concurrent licenses. Kudos if you want to apply internal restrictions to ensure that. The only answer up to now focuses on ensuring concurrent licenses that you *sold* to someone.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer Thomas.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment Thomas. Their argument is feed back from customers who want flexibility to pick the method that works best for them to distribute licenses on a concurrent basis!  So the responsibility to monitor and control the license usage now falls on the customer.  Not surprisingly the cost reflects this license change..... "Because Stata does not have any specific license management facilities built into the software, pricing is no higher for a network license than for a volume purchase for the same number of users."

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm not aware of an existing solution, but IMHO it could be solved by a network share + a small script + a corporate policy. The policy would require to start the software via the script only. The script would increase a number in a text file on the network share when started, then start the software, then decrease the number when the software ended.

Comment: @scoop may I know what program do you need to condtrol?

Comment: @Dude. The software bought was stata. We went with a solution provided by sassafras called K2.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Wibu](http://www.wibu.com/) for this in the past.

They have a range of [licensing](http://www.wibu.com/software-licensing.html) enforcement options available including concurrent.

As a caveat, I haven't bought anything from them for a few years - I haven't needed to.  Their products have probably updated since my last experience of them.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment.  There is a company called Sassafras that specialises in Software Asset Management.  They have a product called K2 which looks promising.  I will update the post as soon as I have completed my testing of the demo they provided. http://www.sassafras.com/